# Import csv function

Tags: sql, csv, sql-server-ce

I'm just after a function to import a csv file. I've read heaps of threads on this but unable to make one for my app. I'm writing a small app that uses a local database. Two databases A and B each with their own table A and B. All I want to do it to be able to export the table rows to a csv and then import them back in to the same tables. Don't care about exporting column names, just the rows. Here's my export code (this works, just writing out the rows to a csv).

```
    private void trackBindingNavigatorExportItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void saveFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (DataRow dr in this.trackDataSet.Track)
        {
            foreach (object field in dr.ItemArray)
            {
                str.Append(field.ToString() + ",");
            }
            str.Replace(",", Environment.NewLine, str.Length - 1, 1);
        }
        string name = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
        try
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(name, str.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What DBMS? Tag your question with it.

Comment: I have an open source command line to to do this, feel free to reuse the code: https://csv2sqlce.codeplex.com/